# Wrapping json member fields to object

Tags: json, go

My objective is to add fields to json on user request.

Everything is great, but when displaying the fields with

```
fmt.Printf("%s: %s\n", content.Date, content.Description)
```

an error occurs:

`invalid character '{' after top-level value`

And that is because after adding new fields the file looks like this:

```
{"Date":"2017-03-20 10:46:48","Description":"new"}
{"Date":"2017-03-20 10:46:51","Description":"new .go"}
```

The biggest problem is with the writting to file

```
reminder := &Name{dateString[:19], text} //text - input string
newReminder, _ := json.Marshal(&reminder)
```

I dont really know how to do this properly

My question is how should I wrap all member fields into one object?
And what is the best way to iterate through member fields?

The code is available here: https://play.golang.org/p/NunV_B6sud

Comment: If you want to wrap in an object you need to marshal as a map and each Reminder needs to have a unique name. However you can also marshal as a slice, JSON allows the root object to be an array.

Comment: I believe your file is missing a root node, ie all the records are siblings without a parent. That is why you are getting the "invalid character '{' after top-level value"

Comment: @Paul, you will have to be clear and specific on what your question is, is it the error when you get when you are reading your .json file? or Marshaling the data in hand?

Comment: @nJoshi I think I was pretty specific with my question and mkopriva has shown exactly what I've wanted although it doesnt work on my machine, while it works on his.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some research, people in the `go-nuts` group helped me and suggested me to use a streaming json parser that parses items individually.

So I needed to change my reminder listing function:

```
func listReminders() error {
    f, err := os.Open("rem.json")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    dec := json.NewDecoder(f)
    for {
        var content Name
        switch dec.Decode(&content) {
        case nil:
            fmt.Printf("%#v\n", content)
        case io.EOF:
            return nil
        default:
            return err
        }
    }
}
```

Now everything works the way I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You should store the reminders into an array inside the json file, as mentioned by @Gerben Jacobs, and then, every time you want to add a new reminder to the array you need to read the full contents of `rem.json`, append the new reminder in Go, truncate the file, and write the new slice into the file. Here's a quick implentation https://play.golang.org/p/UKR91maQF2.

If you have lots of reminders and the process of reading, decoding, encoding, and writing the whole content becomes a pain you could open the file, implement a way to truncate only the last `]` from the file contents, and then write only `,` + new reminder + `]`.

Comment: Well, your example does not work, after adding a reminder it says `EOF` and while displaying them it shows `unexpected end of JSON input`.

Comment: Are you sure you copied the code verbatim? I just ran that example implementation and here's the output: http://imgur.com/TutS0Uv.

Comment: Well that's strange, yes I did, and still the same error occurs also your variable err is redeclared 3 times. I've tried running it both ways.

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't work for you... about the errors though, redeclaring errors is fine as long as they are redeclared inside a new block e.g. `if err := file.Close(); err != nil { ...` or as part of a multi value declaration (`x, y, z := 3, 2, 1`) where at least one of the declared values wasn't declared before in the current block e.g. `info, err := file.Stat()`.